# HTMLAgilityPack QuerySelectorAll throwing exception, potentially Fizzler dll version mismatch?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, fizzler

We recently updated a bunch of dlls in our project, including HtmlAgilityPack to their latest versions. This has made the following code which had been working start throwing errors on the first line.

```
List<HtmlNode> foundNodes = document.QuerySelectorAll(".divider").ToList();

foreach(HtmlNode node in foundNodes){
    doWhatever(node);
}
```

**Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.Descendants()'.**

The last line of the stack trace is:

"**at Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeOps.b__71(HtmlNode n)**"

The QuerySelectorAll is returning an IEnumerable of HtmlNode, however I can't seem to be able to cast it to a list anymore. I would hazard a guess there is some related dll with an incompatible version now (fizzler?) missing the `Descendants` method? However the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/1.4.9.4) for HtmlAgilityPack shows no dependencies, and the fizzler version I'm using is 1.0.0 which I think is correct.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling both `HtmlAgilityPack` and `Fizzler`, and installing their up-to-date versions ?

Comment: Yep, to no avail. Looking deeper at the exception it seems the `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` dll is being loaded from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and is an old version, not sure why. I tried deleting the folder and reloading the project but it somehow is the same. We have started using AngleSharp instead now as it's usage is very similar so it was a simple changeover.

Comment: You using `AngleSharp` was my first guess (`QuerySelectorAll` is familiar to me). I suggest reproducing the problem: create a console app, install the required packages (latest versions), and issue a simple `QuerySelectorAll` call. Does it happen there as well ? If not (and it will likely not), perhaps you can also delete the `packages.config` file and then uninstall all relevant packages ? (the order might be the opposite - uninstall and then delete the file), and try installing again ?

Answer (score 10):

It's happening the same error with me after I upgraded the HtmlAgilityPack nuget package.

I resolved downgrading from 1.4.9.4 to 1.4.9 for now.

Let's see the next versions of this package.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I had already tried this and it didn't solve the issue for me so I'm not going to mark this as the answer (but upvoted)

Comment: Did you removed the files of 1.4.9.4 from packages folder?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

The version 1.5.0 has been released, and this issue has been fixed in the v1.5.0-beta5.

It was caused because a default parameter was added to a method in the v1.4.9.5

Since the library is strongly named, Fizzler could not find anymore this method.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar error, and rolling it back from 1.4.9.5 to version 1.4.9 resolved it, not entirely sure why though.